# Convert rows to constant columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query with its result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DeviceView AS dv
WHERE DeviceId = 5
```

Result:

```
Id      Name                        AttachId        ColorId     Date
---     -------                     ----------      -------     -------
5       Apple iPhone 5s A1533       NULL            1           2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
5       Apple iPhone 5s A1533       NULL            8           2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
5       Apple iPhone 5s A1533       NULL            19          2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
```

ColorId is within diffrent values and it can be more or less than 3 values
I want to convert ColorId to 3 columns, such as first value in `ColorId1` and second value in `ColorId2` and third value in `ColorId3`.
eg:

```
Id      Name                        AttachId    ColorId1    ColorId2    ColorId3    Date
---     -------                     ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------
5       Apple iPhone 5s A1533       NULL        1           8           19          2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
```

How can I convert it to the following?

**Edit**:
All other fields except `ColorId` are the same.

Comment: First, Are all the other columns dependent on the Id? i.e,, Could you have Name = `SamSung Galaxy 4`  on the second row ? or not? Same with `AttachId` and `Date`?

Comment: If these columns are dependent on Id,  then your database has normalization issues., which you should solve first

Comment: @CharlesBretana See edit section of post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this generic query based on PIVOT and CTE's that can easily be extended for any number of colors and that performs very well:

```
-- First, we assign unique numbers to each of the ColorId's. These will become column names
;WITH NumberedColors (ColorId,ColorNumber) AS (
    SELECT ColorId,'Color'+CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColorId)) AS VARCHAR) AS ColorNumber
    FROM dbo.DeviceView
    GROUP BY ColorId
),
-- Here we return the dbo.DeviceView extended with ColorNumber column name
DeviceViewWithNumberedColors (Id,Name,AttachId,[Date],ColorNumber,ColorId) AS (
    SELECT Id,Name,AttachId,Date,NC.ColorNumber,NC.ColorId
          FROM dbo.DeviceView DV
               INNER JOIN NumberedColors NC ON DV.ColorId=NC.ColorId
)
-- Finally, we use the PIVOT to assign color's to the appropriate columns
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT Id,Name,AttachId,[Date],ColorId,ColorNumber
        FROM DeviceViewWithNumberedColors D
     ) AS Source
     PIVOT (
        SUM(ColorId) FOR ColorNumber IN ([Color1],[Color2],[Color3],[Color4],[Color5],[Color6],[Color7],[Color8],[Color9],[Color10])
     ) Piv
```

In the PIVOT clause, make sure you have enough Color columns. If this can not be hard-coded, i.e. the number of colors could grow beyond a fixed number, then use dynamic SQL to generate this query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly three colors, you can use conditional aggregation or pivot:

```
select id, name, attachid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as color1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then color end) as color2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then color end) as color3,
       date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, name, attachid, date;
```

Comment: Thanks, but color ids are more than 3 colors. it's variable

Answer (score 0):

If count of ColorId values is not a fixed number you must use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT Id, Name, AttachId'

SELECT @sql = @sql 
  + ', MAX(IIF(ValueNum = ' + LTRIM(STR(ColumnNum)) + ', ColorId, NULL)) AS ColorId' + LTRIM(STR(ColumnNum))
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ColorId) AS ColumnNum
  FROM dbo.DeviceView
  WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id 
    FROM dbo.DeviceView 
    GROUP BY Id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT ColorId) DESC)
) AS c

EXEC (@sql 
  + ', [Date] FROM ('
  + 'SELECT Id, Name, AttachId, ColorId, [Date], DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ColorId) AS ValueNum FROM dbo.DeviceView'
  + ') AS it '
  + 'GROUP BY Id, Name, AttachId, [Date]');
```